Showing that there is no translation such that $T(P)=Q$
Definition(Translation):  We extend the function $\mathbb{A}^2(K)\to\mathbb{A}^2(K)$, given by the rule $(x,y)\mapsto (x+a,y+b)$, to the transformation of $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by $(x:y:z)\mapsto (x+az:y+bz:z)$.

Verify if the following statement is true or not:
Given two arbitrary points in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$, there exists a translation $T$ such that $T(P)=Q$.
At the beginning I thought it was true, however, I did not account for the point at infinity. This makes me think that the statement is false. Now, I'm not really sure how to prove no such projective transformation (a translation in this case) exists.

What is your definition of a translation of projective space?

$\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$ has not just a point, but a whole line at infinity.

@LazzaroCampeotti The definition I have is: We extend the function $\mathbb{A}^2(K)\to\mathbb{A}^2(K)$, given by the rule $(x,y)\mapsto (x+a,y+b)$, to the transformation of $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by $(x:y:z)\mapsto (x+az:y+bz:z)$.

@ViktorVaughn You are right, I forgot that. It's the one denoted by  $R_{\infty}$. Does considering a point in this line help with the exercise?

The "line at infinity" in your coordinates (recall that there is no actual "line at infinity", it is always an artifact of choosing coordinates) is given by the points of the form $(x : y : 0)$. What is the action of a translation on such a point?

@CaptainLama $T(x:y:0)=(x:y:0)$. Meaning $T$ maps a point at infinity to a point at infinity. Right?

Sure, but not to any point. To itself.
